# show if the member has nitro discord

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make it show 'yes' if the user has, I'm testing with a user who has nitro, but keeps showing 'no'

```
        .addField('Nitro', `${member.premiumSubscriptionCount ? 'Yes' : 'No'}`,true)
```

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, you cannot get if the user has Nitro with a bot, however you make a user authorize using your [OAuth](https://discord.com/developers/applications) which you can get the user's info

You can also get if the [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user) has an animated avatar with `User.displayAvatarURL({dynamic:true}).endsWith('.gif')` (only Nitro or Nitro classic users can use animated avatars)

You can also get [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user).[flags](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=flags) but it doesn't include if they have Nitro or not.

Answer (score -2):

[`premiumSubscriptionCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=premiumSubscriptionCount) is a [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) property (what boost level the guild is at), so if you call it on a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), it will return undefined. You should use [`GuildMember.premiumSince`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=premiumSince).

```js
.addField('Nitro', member.premiumSince ? 'Yes' : 'No', true)
```

Comment: this checks if the user has boosted the server, not if they have nitro