# Not able to check if user has discord nitro or no

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to check if user has discord nitro (classic or $10 one, doesn't matter) using `user.flags.toArray()`, as far as I know - you can't use it to check if someone has nitro. Is there any way how you can actually check it without making someone to authorize using my OAuth?

P.S. I know there was one similar question but it was never answered!

Comment: What was the similar question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [show if the member has nitro discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64176454/show-if-the-member-has-nitro-discord)

Comment: @MalikLahlou It's the question I was talking about, and as I said, there is no valid answer

Comment: The why are you searching again for info- ? Discord's API doesn't and won't tell us if a member has a nitro subscribtion because they don't want bots to priviledge users who have nitro than other users It's Discord's choice and it shall be respected :/

Answer (score 0):

Don't check the flags of the account, check the `premium_type`

More information is available in their documentation:
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object-user-structure
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object-premium-types

Cheers! :)

Comment: But how can I check premium type? When I'm trying to use `user.premium_type` I just get `undefined` as result

Comment: you need to have `identify` scope on your OAuth2 token.

Comment: > without making someone to authorize using my OAuth